# How to set timeout for each route in Spring Cloud Gateway?

Tags: spring-cloud, spring-cloud-gateway

Is there a way to set different timeout values for each route in Spring cloud gateway?
eg
/route1 - 30s
/route2 - 20s

Comment: mark the answer if it works for you

Answer (score 3):

Yes, We can do the same by defining different `hystrix` command for different routes. Consider the following example, where for `route_1` the timeout is 15 seconds, as the `hystrix` command used here `default` is configured with a timeout of 15 seconds.

```
 # ===========================================
 # Timeout 15 seconds
  - id: route_1
    uri: ${test.uri}
    predicates:
    - Path=/timeout/**
    filters:
    - name: Hystrix
      args:
        name: default
        fallbackUri: forward:/hystrixfallback

hystrix.command.default.execution.isolation.thread.timeoutInMilliseconds: 15000
```

Now for `route_2` the the `hystrix` command used is `applicationTimeOut` with a timeout of 5 seconds.

```
# ===========================================
  # Timeout 5 seconds
  - id: route_2
    uri: ${test.uri}/count
    predicates:
    - Path=/count
    filters:
    - name: Hystrix
      args:
        name: applicationTimeOut
        fallbackUri: forward:/hystrixfallback

hystrix.command.applicationTimeOut.execution.isolation.thread.timeoutInMilliseconds: 5000
```

Now for `route_3` the the `hystrix` command used is `apiTimeOut` with a timeout of 2 seconds.

```
# ===========================================   
  # Timeout 2 seconds
    - id: route_3
    uri: ${test.uri}
    predicates:
    - Path=/event/**
    filters:
    - name: Hystrix
      args:
        name: apiTimeOut
        fallbackUri: forward:/hystrixfallback
hystrix.command.apiTimeOut.execution.isolation.thread.timeoutInMilliseconds: 2000
```

Answer (score 2):

According to Spring Cloud Gateway documentation this is much simpler:

https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-gateway/reference/html/#per-route-timeouts

So you can configure connect and read timeouts per each route, like this:

```
  - id: per_route_timeouts
    uri: https://example.org
    predicates:
      - name: Path
        args:
          pattern: /delay/{timeout}
    metadata:
      response-timeout: 200
      connect-timeout: 200
```

Comment: Please note that this is not affecting Hystrix timeout.