# Is there a default request timeout in the Spring Cloud Gateway?

Tags: spring-cloud-gateway

In the [documentation](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-gateway/single/spring-cloud-gateway.html) I did see how timeouts can be implemented using Hystrix, but I just want to make sure there is not a default timeout implemented.

Answer (score 0):

There is now also a [chapter](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-gateway/reference/html/#http-timeouts-configuration) about general timeouts in the documentation. It is possible to set global timeouts and per-route timeouts. I was not able to find the default values, but it seems there is no default timeout at all (HTTP request was in progress for several minutes when I did not include the timeout config). In addition to the spring-cloud-gateway timeouts it is still possible to also use hystrix timeouts, as described for example in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51484050/4311428).

Global timeouts:

```
spring:
  cloud:
    gateway:
      httpclient:
        connect-timeout: 1000
        response-timeout: 5000
```

Per-route timeouts:

```
  - id: per_route_timeouts
    uri: https://example.org
    predicates:
      - name: Path
        args:
          pattern: /delay/{timeout}
    metadata:
      response-timeout: 200
      connect-timeout: 200
```

Per-route timeouts with Java DSL:

```
import static org.springframework.cloud.gateway.support.RouteMetadataUtils.CONNECT_TIMEOUT_ATTR;
import static org.springframework.cloud.gateway.support.RouteMetadataUtils.RESPONSE_TIMEOUT_ATTR;

  @Bean
  public RouteLocator customRouteLocator(RouteLocatorBuilder routeBuilder){
     return routeBuilder.routes()
           .route("test1", r -> {
              return r.host("*.somehost.org").and().path("/somepath")
                    .filters(f -> f.addRequestHeader("header1", "header-value-1"))
                    .uri("http://someuri")
                    .metadata(RESPONSE_TIMEOUT_ATTR, 200)
                    .metadata(CONNECT_TIMEOUT_ATTR, 200);
           })
           .build();
  }
```

Comment: For me its not working https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64935162/spring-cloud-gate-request-timeout-not-working-for-path can you help on it?